# Command line equivalent of Subclipse Branch/Tag command

Tags: svn, version-control, subclipse

I'd like to tag only a subset of my subdirectories. In Subclipse I can mark several subdirectories and only tag them. E.g.

```
BigProject/
  SubProjectA/
  SubProjectB/
  SubProjectC/
```

Now I want do `svn copy` only on say `BigProject/` with `SubProjectA` and `SubProjectB`. How is the command line version of selecting the sub projects in Subclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I think of the svn copy command as basically the same command as the Unix 'cp' command.  Either way that you do this it will take multiple steps.

From the command line you would:

```
svn mkdir /path_to_your_repo/new_tag
svn cp /path_to_your_repo/BigProject/SubProjectA /path_to_your_repo/new_tag/
```

You can also do this in the [SVN Explorer perspective](http://subclipse.tigris.org/screenshots.html) in Subclipse.